# How to make template html to table have first column dividing to 4 cell and second column only one cell?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I work on template using html and CSS . I face issue  on design table template using html and CSS

Issue i face on second rows it have 4 cell in first column and one cell for second column

in first column have header `performance` and second cell divide to 4 cell .

on second column have header `disciplinary` and only one cell on  second row

so How to make design to this table

what I try

```
<table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>
                  Performance Rating for
                  last two years
              </th>
              <th>Disciplinary letters (in last two years)</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr> <th>Year</th> <th></th> <th></th> </tr>
          <tr> <th>Year</th> <th></th>  <th></th> </tr>


      </tbody>
  </table>
```

web design for table desired below :

[image: issue column dividing to two cell]

**updated post**

can you show me how to do that by colspan and rowspan?

yes it working but I need to increase width of second cell beside year

under `performance rating column`

```
<table border="1">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th colspan="2">
                  Performance Rating for
                  last two years
              </th>
              <th>Disciplinary letters (in last two years)</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr colspan="2">
            <td>Year</td>
            <td ></td>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
          </tr>
           <tr colspan="2"> 
             <td >Year</td>
             <td></td>
           </tr>
           
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: colspan, rowspan?

Comment: can you show me please

Comment: Hope it will help you https://jsfiddle.net/wp3crdou/2/

Comment: no need year for cell under Disciplinary letter

Comment: yes working but need to increase cell beside Year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue using col span and row span

and this is my code

```
<table border="1">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th colspan="2">
                  Performance Rating for
                  last two years
              </th>
              <th>Disciplinary letters (in last two years)</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr colspan="2">
            <td style="width:50px;">Year</td>
            <td ></td>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
          </tr>
           <tr colspan="2"> 
             <td style="width:50px;">Year</td>
             <td></td>
           </tr>
           
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: you simply took my code from fiddle and pasted as answer. You should have asked me to put as answer so i can put more details so you and future user can get the main point but ok. hope it helps.

Comment: @Leothelion rather than creating a fiddle, you should have answered the question yourself using a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2518285).

Comment: @BrettDonald i wasn't sure he was looking for this answer so i asked user if it helps. If he said yes then i was going to paste as answer but user himself paste an answer so what can i do in this case?

Comment: @Leothelion you can't fix this one, but you can learn for next time. Next time, post your suggestion as an answer right from the start. If the OP does not find it helpful, they can downvote it. If you get several downvotes, you can always delete your answer and recover your reputation.

Comment: But then it will be against rule as i cant post the answer till confirm from client side or else it will increase the garbage on SO. Yes i will try better next time to give the answer. Thank you for your suggestion.